# Installation Error on MAAS configuration

Tags: server, maas

I want to install 64 bit architecture Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server.

I am having problem while I select option for MAAS server installation.
When script for "select and install package" is running, every time
it is stopped and if I skip that stage; then grub installation is failed.

So I don't assume that it is a hardware error. I want to know whether that can be solved or not. And not any option for server installation is working on the machine.
That machine is having Intel Xenon Processor.

Comment: Did you [MD5SUM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) the ISO file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if you're running into this while installing the server, and you're hitting some kind of problem that's not really related to MAAS itself.  I've seen machines that had trouble setting up Grub, although that was a long time ago.

You may want to see if a regular install does work.  If a regular install fails, then you know it's not really a MAAS-related problem and there will be more sources of help for the problem.